# How to set which browser to use in a QTextBrowser link?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am using PyQt4's QTextBroswer to display a html link.

Whenever users click on the link, a browser will be used to open the internet page.

My question is, is there a way to set so that our own prefered browser is used to open the url page instead of the preset one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that it doesn't use `webbrowser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTextBrowser` *provides* an actual browser. If you want to open a document in the user's desktop environment-specified browser, then you'd use [QDesktopServices::openUrl](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl).

You can use [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#details) to start random programs:

```
QObject *parent;
...
QString program = "/path/to/browser";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "--your-browser-url-option-if-any" << "http://www.example.com";

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the trolltech site, but just couldn't seem to get a clue how to use the QUrl to set our own desired browser.
Can please explain to me more detail about it? 
Sorry I'm kinda new to these browser thingie.

Comment: You can't. You can either use QTextBrowser's own browser, QDesktopServices::openUrl with the user's default browser, or QProcess and start the browser you want with the link as an argument.

Comment: @lionel319: Opening with a specific browser will be a platform dependent operation that you would have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you or this is what you were looking for. I found that by setting the openExternalLinks flag to True I was able to get the link to open in Firefox. 
I just called the [setOpenExternalLinks](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtextbrowser.html#setOpenExternalLinks) method with *True* as argument.

This method is only for using the default browser and won't let you to actually set the browser.

Comment: It opened in firefox because thats your default browser. But you didn't tell it to open with firefox.